# Permission issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter

I am facing problem regarding permission

Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}() must be an instance of App\Providers\User, instance of App\User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tweety\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 473 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tweety\resources\views\tweet.blade.php)

I am just working to show delete button only on those tweets made by the authenticated users

my controller

```
  public function destroy(Tweet $tweet)
      {

          $tweet->delete();
          Session::flash('success');
          return redirect()->route('tweets.index')->with(['message' => 'Tweet Deleted']);

      }
```

my user model

```
 public function tweets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tweet::class)->latest();
    }
```

my blade

```
 @can('delete',$tweet)
                <form action="{{ route('tweets.destroy',$tweet->id) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            @endcan
```

AuthServiceProvider

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('delete', function (User $user , Tweet $tweet){
           return  $tweet->user->is($user);
        });
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In `AuthServiceProvider`, did you import User class correctly? looks like it's namespace issue. `use App\User`

Comment: please post full code for `AuthServiceProvider`

Comment: yes it was the issue of namespace, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a namespace issue and didn't import User model's namespace correctly.

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Providers;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
    use App\User; // looks like you're missing this line.
    use App\Tweet;

    class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * The policy mappings for the application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $policies = [
            'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        ];
    
        /**
         * Register any authentication / authorization services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
         public function boot()
         {
             $this->registerPolicies();

             Gate::define('delete', function (User $user , Tweet $tweet){
                return  $tweet->user->is($user);
             });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change:

```
@can('delete', $tweet)
```

to:

```
@can('delete')
```